# Emulate uint32_t in Python?

Tags: python

I was trying to port a function from C to Python and to make it easy to debug, I'd prefer it performed the same CPU word-size limited operations so I could compare the intermediate results. In other words, I'd like something like:

```
a = UnsignedBoundedInt(32, 399999)
b = UnsignedBoundedInt(32, 399999)
print(a*b) # prints 1085410049 (159999200001 % 2**32)
```

What's the best way to achieve this so that all operations (including bitwise shifts) would work as in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an interesting solution, though it only works under Python 2:

```
class U32:
    """Emulates 32-bit unsigned int known from C programming language."""

    def __init__(self, num=0, base=None):
        """Creates the U32 object.

        Args:
            num: the integer/string to use as the initial state
            base: the base of the integer use if the num given was a string
        """
        if base is None:
            self.int_ = int(num) % 2**32
        else:
            self.int_ = int(num, base) % 2**32

    def __coerce__(self, ignored):
        return None

    def __str__(self):
        return "<U32 instance at 0x%x, int=%d>" % (id(self), self.int_)

    def __getattr__(self, attribute_name):
        print("getattr called, attribute_name=%s" % attribute_name)
        # you might want to take a look here:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/q/19611001/1091116
        r = getattr(self.int_, attribute_name)
        if callable(r):  # return a wrapper if integer's function was requested
            def f(*args, **kwargs):
                if args and isinstance(args[0], U32):
                    args = (args[0].int_, ) + args[1:]
                ret = r(*args, **kwargs)
                if ret is NotImplemented:
                    return ret
                if attribute_name in ['__str__', '__repr__', '__index__']:
                    return ret
                ret %= 2**32
                return U32(ret)
            return f
        return r

print(U32(4) / 2)
print(4 / U32(2))
print(U32(4) / U32(2))
```

For Python 3 compatibility, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20430720/1091116).

Answer (score 26):

You can try using `ctypes.uint_32` to bound the results for you:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> print ctypes.c_uint32(399999 * 399999).value
1085410049
```

Alternatively you can use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)'s data types:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.uint32(399999)
>>> b = np.uint32(399999)
>>> a * b
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in uint_scalars
1085410049
```

Comment: v1 -= ((v0 << 4 ^ v0 >> 5) + v0) ^ (sum + k[sum>>11 & 3])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'c_uint' and 'int'

Comment: And: >>> type(numpy.uint32(3) << 4)
<type 'numpy.int64'>

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'c_uint' and 'c_uint'

Comment: So, looks like it's not exactly the best solution.

Comment: @d33tah You forgot about the `.value` in the `ctypes` case. Besides, you should put this "clipping operation" one level towards the outside. That is, if you have `clip_u32 = lambda val: ctypes.c_uint32(val).value`, you could do `v1 -= clip_u32((v0 << 4 ^ v0 >> 5) + v0) ^ clip_u32(sum + k[sum>>11 & 3])`.

Comment: @d33tah: With the `ctypes` approach you have to always convert to py ints and convert back for each op. Not the nicest approach, true. `numpy` does more what you want. Alternatively you can subclass int yourself and override all the ops to do the ctypes conversion & back

Answer (score 2):

### Acheiving this using the arbitrary precision integers in Python

Certain math operations are safe to chain where you can delay computing the modulus until later. Examples of this is `+`, `-`, `*`, `<<` (right shift).

```py
((a%c) + (b%c)) % c == (a + b) % c
((a%c) - (b%c)) % c == (a - b) % c
((a%c) * (b%c)) % c == (a * b) % c
((a%c) << (b%c)) % c == (a << b) % c
```

Others are not, like `/`, `//`, `%` (modulo) and `>>` (left shift).

Also note that when our modulo is a power of 2, we can replace the operation with a bitwise AND operation - which essentially zeros out the binary digits you don't want.

```py
x % (2**n) == x & (2**n - 1)
```

So for 32 bit operations, that becomes:

```py
x % (2**32) == x & 0xFFFFFFFF
```

That means in order to match the result of u32-operations in C/numpy, you could perform `x & 0xFFFFFFFF` for every intermediate result of your computation. You can temporarily skip this for certain operations as highlighted above.

This doesn't require any dependencies, and is less verbose than using
`ctypes.c_uint32(...).value` for every intermediate result.

---

When `p == 2**n`, certain bitwise operations also make it safe to delay the modulo operation.

```py
((a%p) & (b%p)) % p == (a & b) % p  # BITWISE AND
((a%p) | (b%p)) % p == (a | b) % p  # BITWISE OR
((a%p) ^ (b%p)) % p == (a ^ b) % p  # BITWISE XOR
```