# How to implement C-like unsigned int 32 in Python with no external dependencies?

Tags: python

I need a class that would keep all the Python's functionality of `int` class, but make sure its results are within 32-bit integers, just like in C programming language. The type has to be "poisonous" - performing an operation on int and this type should result in returning this type. As suggested in one of the answers [to my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233055/emulate-uint32-t-in-python), I used to use `numpy.uint32` for this purpose, but it feels too silly to add such a big dependency just for a single, relatively simple, type. How do I achieve that? Here are my attempts so far:

```
MODULO = 7  # will be 2**32 later on

class u32:
    def __init__(self, num = 0, base = None):
        print(num)
        if base is None:
            self.int = int(num) % MODULO
        else:
            self.int = int(num, base) % MODULO
    def __coerce__(self, x):
        return None
    def __str__(self):
        return "<u32 instance at 0x%x, int=%d>" % (id(self), self.int)
    def __getattr__(self, x):
        r = getattr(self.int, x)
        if callable(r):
            def f(*args, **kwargs):
                ret = r(*args, **kwargs) % MODULO
                print("x=%s, args=%s, kwargs=%s, ret=%s" % (x, args, kwargs, ret))
                if x not in ['__str__', '__repr__']:
                    return u32(ret)
                return r(*args, **kwargs)
            return f
        return r

u = u32(4)
print("u/2")
a = u * 2
assert(isinstance(a, u32))

print("\n2/u")
a = 2 * u
assert(isinstance(a, u32))

print("\nu+u")
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "u32.py", line 44, in <module>
    a = u + u
  File "u32.py", line 18, in f
    ret = r(*args, **kwargs) % MODULO
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NotImplementedType' and 'int'
"""
a = u + u
assert(isinstance(a, u32))
```

Comment: Is the necessity out of memory storage or compatibility ?

Comment: Compatibility. I need to be able to copy some formulas from C to Python and they rely on the overflow behavior.

Comment: Other than "silliness", why not using `numpy`? Fine work has already been done, for you to enjoy.

Comment: I'd rather keep C-compiled code to minimum, so I'd prefer to keep this type in pure Python. Also, I'm interested in how would that look like.

Comment: Did you consider using `ctypes` ?

Comment: After my experiences with Cygwin, I decided to avoid ctypes. Also, not sure how it's supported in other Python implementations, like Jython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obviously correct method is going to be to write all the special methods (which can be a pain).

Otherwise, try this for your `__getattr__`

```
def __getattr__(self, x):
    r = getattr(self.int, x)
    if callable(r):
        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            if args and isinstance(args[0], u32):
                args = (args[0].int, ) + args[1:]
            ret = r(*args, **kwargs)
            if ret is NotImplemented:
                return ret
            if x in ['__str__', '__repr__', '__cmp__', '__index__']:
                return ret
            ret %= MODULO
            return u32(ret)
        return f
    return r
```

As Martijn notes, this only works for old-style classes.  See [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20430720/208880) for a method that works with new-style classes.

Comment: I already tried the version without % MODULO. Has the same problem.

Comment: @d33tah: Okay, try this one.

Comment: self.int = int(num) % MODULO
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: @d33tah: Do you still have the `__coerce__` method in place?  Which operations gives that error?

Comment: `struct.unpack()` returns a tuple.  ;)

Comment: @d33tah: and you'll want to add `__index__` to the exclusions.

Comment: What a silly mistake! Looks like the code works now that I applied your changes. Thank you! :)

Comment: `u32(2) == 2`: `TypeError: comparison did not return an int`

Comment: @shx2: Added `__cmp__` to list of non-wrapped items.

Comment: Note, this works **only** on old-style classes. On new-style classes, special methods are looked up on the **type** (so for instances, on the class), bypassing any `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` hooks, on the instance, the class *and* the meta type!

Comment: See the [Special Method lookup](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) as to why this is so. I present a workaround in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20430720.