# Python 3.4 __getattr__ being called for attributes that (should?) exist

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following class which is meant to imitate a `dict` without actually being a subclass:

```
class DB:

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print('__getattribute__("%s")' % name)
        if name.startswith('__') and name not in ['__init__', '__new__',
                '__dict__', '__getattribute__', '__getattr__', '__setattr__',
                '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__module__', '__del__', '__hash__']:
            return eval('self._d.%s' % name)
        print('it is not being diverted to self._d')
        raise AttributeError(name)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print('__getattr__("%s")' % name)
        if name.startswith('__'):
            raise AttributeError(name)
        return eval('self._d.%s' % name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        if name == '_d':
            self.__dict__[name] = val
        else:
            return self._d.__setattr__(name, val)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        if name == '_d':
            del self.__dict__[name]
        else:
            return self._d.__delattr__(name)

    def __init__(self):
        self._d = {}
```

This produces the following output when used:

```
>>> d = DB()
__getattribute__("__dict__")
it is not being diverted to self._d
__getattr__("__dict__")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    d = DB()
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 31, in __init__
    self._d = {}
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 20, in __setattr__
    self.__dict__[name] = val
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 15, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __dict__
```

Shouldn't it never get to `__getattr__("__dict__")`, since `self.__dict__` should already exist by virtue of this being an object?

I have been using this object (well, an essentially identical object) successfully in a program I have been using for several months in Python 2.6 and am trying to upgrade to Python 3.4. According to everything I can find online, Python 3 should be treating this the same as Python 2.

*Edit:* Similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430637) but that question deals with `__getattr__` not being called at all. Both are apparently related to new-style vs. old-style classes, though.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430637/python-3-getattr-behaving-differently-than-in-python-2), which suggest that since you did not inherit from object, you were creating an old-style class under Python2. Quick test with `class DB(object):` under Python2 shows a similar error ...

Comment: @BasSwinckels: the OP tagged the question as Python 3.x, which doesn't have old-style classes.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, adding object will break the code in the same way in python2

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I know, but the fact that Python2 does have them explains why his old code broke.

Comment: @BasSwinckels && Padraic: yes sorry, missed part of the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding `__getattribute__` - which is the default implementation for attribute lookup - in such a way that it raises a `NameError` when looking up `__dict__`. This triggers the call to `__getattr__`, which in turn raises an `AttributeError`. The result is *exactly* what you actually asked for (if not what you expected).

FWIW:

1. as a general rule, don't use `eval("self.%s" % name)`, use `getattr(obj, name)`
2. don't override `__getattribute__` (nor`__setattr__`) unless you *really* understand what you're doing
3. if you really *have* to override them (hint: there are very very very few reasons to do so), delegate to the default implementation (using `super()`).

Also: the code you posted doesn't work "as is" in Python 2.7 (the call to `self._d.__setattr__` raises an AttributeError, and making `DB` a new-style class breaks in exactly the same way as in Python 3.x.

Comment: So it looks like what you're saying is that because `__getattribute__` raises an AttributeError, that error means Python no longer looks for whether `__dict__` exists, and so it goes straight to `__getattr__`? (And, FWIW, how can I _really_ understand what I'm doing unless I override `__getattribute__` once in a while? Thanks for the tips, tho.)

Comment: "because `__getattribute__` raises an AttributeError, that error means Python no longer looks for whether `__dict__` exists" => Yes, that's *exactly* the point.